# Remove phantom newline character from scraped xml feed

Tags: php, string, str-replace, removing-whitespace

I am trying to remove all extra whitespace characters from a string in php. The string source is from an xml feed of customer reviews.

A few reviews have just too much whitespace and they are showing up in my html! Whether that be... The spacebar being hit too many times, the carriage return, or a newline, I just want a maximum of one space `' '` between characters.

```
$review = str_replace(array('\n','\r\n',PHP_EOL,'\0','\t'), '', $reviewText[1]);
$review = trim(ereg_replace(' +', ' ', $review));
```

I have also tried using `preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $review);` instead of the `trim(ereg_replace(` line

Despite my best efforts, I still can't get this invisible whitespace / newline character to disappear.

Any ideas?

I have pasted the review below with xxx to replace any kind of identifying information. This is the output from a `var_dump($review);`

Here is the review below:

http://www.mangomm.co.uk/test/string.php

Comment: What is the input and expected output?

Comment: You should replace '\r\n' before '\n'.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im I have pasted the input text into http://pastie.org/5651839 I want to remove all those newline characters in the string.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im yes it is. The above code is within a foreach loop. foreach($reviews as $review)

Comment: OP, please read my post -- I just edited it.

Comment: See updated question with var_dump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[rtrim()](http://prototype.php.net/rtrim)
[ltrim()](http://prototype.php.net/ltrim)
[trim()](http://prototype.php.net/trim)

These should do what you're looking for.

`trim('----')` should output ''

`rtrim('----a----');` should output '----a'

`ltrim('----a----');` should output 'a----'

Each hyphen represents a space.

EDIT:

And *after* I read your post :)

Is the new line a break line (`<br>, <br />` etc)? `print_r` doesn't convert text to htmlentities

Comment: I dont know what the newlines are... I didn't write the review you see... But when I print_r, it keeps the newlines in, whatever they are.

Comment: Use `var_dump()` instead of `print_r`, it will show you what it is.

Comment: Oh right, I guess not everyone has xdebug installed :) Yeah, it appears that you have a br tag, what happens when you do `strip_tags($review)`?

Comment: what's this xdebug about then??

Answer (score 1):

`ereg_*` functions are [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ereg-replace.php). Dont use them.

The following regex should work

```
preg_replace('/[[:space:]]+/', ' ', $review);
```

`[:space:]` matches white space characters. In the **"C"** and **"POSIX"** locales, these are  space, form-feed (`\f`), newline (`\n`), carriage return  (`\r`),  horizontal tab (`\t`), and vertical tab (`\v`)

Comment: Thanks for that. But doesn't do anything. See updated question with link to outputted text.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work for me. It appears as though the pastie didn't actually copy the invisible newline character over.

Comment: @Gravy if it does not work then you dont have invisible white space characters. I think they are something else. Could you `var_dump` it?